# How do I encrypt text to an MD5 hash in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, hash, md5

I want to calculate the MD5 Hash of `RichTextBox1.Text`. I've added this line of code at the top so that I can use the MD5 encryption method: `Imports System.Security.Cryptography`. How do I go about actually calculating the hash?

Comment: MD5 is no encryption.

Comment: I remember watching a video where they used `System.Security.Cryptography` to encrypt text into an md5 hash.

Comment: [MD5 Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.md5(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Note: The video was very bad quality. The only thing that stood out clearly was the class name and the namespace.

Comment: That's for console... Not VB.NET.

Answer (score 0):

The process is described [here](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?678890-Get-MD5-Hash-From-String).

The basic code from the link is:

```
Dim Bytes() As Byte
Dim sb As New StringBuilder() 

Bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(RichTextBox1.Text)

'Get md5 hash
Bytes = MD5.Create().ComputeHash(Bytes)

'Loop though the byte array and convert each byte to hex.
For x As Integer = 0 To Bytes.Length - 1
    sb.Append(Bytes(x).ToString("x2"))
Next

'Return md5 hash.
Return sb.ToString()
```

Comment: no positive votes?